# How to show better output explanation in python

Tags: python

```
numbers = input("Enter your numbers: ").split(',')

numbers= [int(i) for i in numbers]

sum_numbers = sum(numbers)

print("Sum: ", sum_numbers)
```

My input is:

```
20,30,50
```

And output is:

```
Sum : 100
```

But I want a better output explanation. I mean this output (Sum : 100) should be ( Sum (20+30+50) : 100 ) this. Is there any solution?

Comment: Do you mean `print(f"Sum ({'+'.join((str(i) for i in numbers)}): {sum_numbers}")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
numbers = input("Enter your numbers: ").split(',')
output = ' +'.join(numbers)
numbers= [int(i) for i in numbers]
sum_numbers = sum(numbers)
print("Sum: (",output,'):', sum_numbers)
```

### Output

```
Sum: ( 20 + 30 + 50  ): 100
```

Answer (score 0):

@sayse, I tried your suggestion and it didn't work. So I have tried to edit it to this:

```
print("Sum ({}): {}".format('+'.join((str(i) for i in numbers)), sum_numbers))
```

Worked well.